# How to add a limit while performing $match stage in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

When doing find() query, I am able to pass options such as limit and sort. This, I assume, means that the database will stop trying to filter matching documents after limit number of documents have been found.

When trying to accomplish the same thing with an aggregation pipeline, I put the same query from the find() as the $match stage, but i cannot specify a limit.

The problem with $limit is that it only occurs in the next stage, so mongo will have processed every single document in the collection before passing it to the next stage, which can become very slow as the collection increases in size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The aggregation framework acts like a stream, so if you have a `$limit` stage in your pipeline, it will stop processing once the limit is reached.

For example:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id": 0 }
{ "_id": 1 }
{ "_id": 2 }
{ "_id": 3 }
{ "_id": 4 }
```

Let's say I want to use a `$match` stage followed by `$limit` stage. Using `explain()` on the aggregation:

```
> db.test.explain('executionStats').aggregate([
      {$match: {_id: {$lte: 3}}},
      {$limit: 1}
  ])
...
        "executionStats": {
          "executionSuccess": true,
          "nReturned": 1,
          "executionTimeMillis": 0,
          "totalKeysExamined": 1,
          "totalDocsExamined": 1,
...
```

The explain output shows that MongoDB only examined 1 key (`totalKeysExamined: 1`) and 1 document (`totalDocsExamined: 1`) to return 1 document (`nReturned: 1`) due to the `$limit` stage. This is despite I'm specifying it to match `_id <= 3`, which should select 4 documents.

Note that most stages work like this, with the exception of stages such as `$group` which needs to gather all the required documents before it can perform grouping on them. Putting `$limit` after `$group` will not make the `$limit` stage act as a stream, since it has to wait for the `$group` stage to finish its process before it can limit the output.

Check out [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) and [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/) for more information.

Comment: Won't this run match first, fetching the entire database for that collection, then limiting? Could be potential memory issues?

Comment: No, most stages in the aggregation pipeline are lazy by default (they won't pull data unless they really need to). Notable exceptions are stages that need to collect all the documents like $group

Comment: match pulls everything it "matches" though.

Comment: No it only pulls the matching documents needed by the subsequent stages.

Comment: So the order is wrong, shouldn't sort and limit be first then?

Comment: No it's not. $match as the first stage will allow index use and limit what needs to be sorted and coupled with lazyness will only pull the required number of documents and no more. Have a read though https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/ especially the $sort + $match Sequence Optimization section: `When you have a sequence with $sort followed by a $match, the $match moves before the $sort to minimize the number of objects to sort`. There are many others internal optimizations built into the query planner that will rearrange stages to make them more optimal.

Comment: You answered your own fault. ```{$limit: 1}``` should be before the match so the optimizer can move it. You answer is slightly wrong. Good we explored this.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#improve-performance-with-indexes-and-document-filters says `$match can use an index to filter documents if $match is the first stage in a pipeline.` I don't know what make you think limit should go before match, but I'm glad you feel better that you think I'm wrong :)

Comment: Hey, it's wrong. We just fixed a bug right now where we had to move the limit and sort above the match in the pipeline to fix it.

Comment: If you think it's wrong, please open a [SERVER ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER) and explain your use case. Please provide the complete reproduction steps, along with any example data you used to determine that this is actually an issue.